# How I can change order of fields for feature in HERE Data Hub space?

Tags: here-api

Seems, that the order of feature fields is define some randomly after feature creation. Can I impact somehow on it ?

Example:

[image]

for instance - can I change order in this dictionary for "amenity" and "capacity" while I creating a feature in HERE Data Hub ?